# (KnockoutJS) How to reset select statement

Tags: knockout.js

I have select options populated by KnockoutJS

Related part of HTML:

```
<label>Gender:</label> 
<select data-bind="options: gender, value: selectedGender, optionsText: 'gender'"></select>
```

And related part of app.js:

```
this.gender = ko.observableArray([{gender: '', value: ''},{gender: 'F', value: 'female'},{gender: 'M', value: 'male'}]);
this.selectedGender = ko.observable();

kn.constructorEnd(this);

var self = this;
this.selectedGenderVal = ko.computed(function () { 
    return self.selectedGender() && self.selectedGender().value; 
})
```

Then I have added data-bind on click event to my modal close icon. All observable data are cleared except that select above which I try to clear doing that:

```
self.selectedGender("");
```

Any clue why is not setting it to an empty value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select control is set up without a "selectedValue" binding, so by default the entire option object will be stored in your "selectedGender" observable. Therefore when you try to select the empty-string value the select control doesn't know how to translate that into one of the options objects in your array.

If you add the `optionsValue: 'gender'` binding then it knows to compare values using the string value in the gender observable rather than comparing whole objects against each other.

Comment: Adding `optionsValue: 'gender'` to the binding just makes that observable value for selection is not selected (passing an empty selection value)

Comment: @JackTheKnife Isn't that what you wanted? Perhaps I misunderstood your question

Comment: My code - I was able to select Male of Female and pass proper value but after closing I was not able to reset to default state. Adding your suggestion and selecting Male of Female is not working at all - is passing an empty value for any selection.

Comment: @JackTheKnife Here's an example without the modal, but the selection and the clear button work. https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/f0ha61xe/

Comment: And here you have your code with submit - no value on selection https://jsfiddle.net/pwrkgsmL/

Comment: @JackTheKnife That's the same code. I don't see any differences

Comment: @JackTheKnife the selectedGender observable is only storing the comparison value now which is a string. So you'll have to update your selectedGenderVal computed accordingly, or rewrite the select binding to use objects instead of string comparison. What precisely do you want the computed to output?

Comment: F for Female selection and M for Male selection

Comment: @JackTheKnife Then you don't need a computed at all. Submit the selectedGender instead of selectedGenderVal